# Pandas: how to write csv file using data from a dataframe as part of path/filename

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas: how to write csv file using data from a dataframe as part of path/filename

I have an example dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
print df

          0
a -0.899348
b  0.297170
c -0.998461
d  0.651564
e  2.013107
```

and a second dataframe with a single column containing a full path/filename

```
data2 = {'filepath': ['C:\\test\\testsub\\testfile.csv']}
path = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['filepath'])
print path

                       filepath
0  C:\test\testsub\testfile.csv
```

I can write the first dataframe to a csv like this:

```
df.to_csv('C:\\test\\testsub\\testfile.csv')
```

But I can't find a way to set the path/filename from the 'path' dataframe.

```
df.to_csv(path['filepath'])
```

...returns an error:

```
'TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found'
```

It seems the dataframe needs some form of conversion in order to be used here. I can't find any information on this. Can anybody enlighten me as to how I can make this work? Any and all help appreciated.

(In the bigger picture, the process is part of a loop where the required path/filename is returned in the dataframe 'path'. I can print the path and filename exactly as they should be, but I can't write the csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make sure that you're extracting a single element from the `filepath` column, rather that passing the whole column as the filename. You can do this with an indexing method like `.ix[]` or `.iloc[]`:

```
current_filepath = path['filepath'].iloc[0]

current_filepath
Out[8]: 'C:\\test\\testsub\\testfile.csv'

df.to_csv(current_filepath)
```

Because your example dataframe `path` just has integer indexes, you can also just do:

```
path['filepath'][0]
```

but this won't work the same way if you have a different index.

Comment: thankyou very much for your help. Your suggestion works perfectly for the example. You point out that the solution won't work with a different index, and I realise my example with a single row is inadequate. Can this solution be adapted for a dataframe with multiple rows?

Comment: @user2904588: In `current_filepath = path['filepath'].iloc[0]`, the `0` just represents the row number. If you loop through row numbers and use `current_filepath = path['filepath'].iloc[row_num]`, it should work.

Comment: Thanks again Marius, I'm still not getting this -- can I ask you for a little more detail? I can't figure out how to sync the row number. eg the loop in your example would be `for row_num in ?`

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. The original answer works well and is appreciated, my fault that the original question didn't reflect my  requirement well enough.